# IBM Circuit Composer pane is blank

Tags: ibm-q-experience

I'm new to IBM Quantum Experience. When I initially create a circuit using the composer, all is well, but when I save the circuit and open it again, the composer window is blank - no gates or wires. I have tried it under Safari, Chrome, and Firefox on a MacBook Pro running 10.11.6 and on an iPad. I have tried disabling content blockers. Java, JavaScript, and Flash are all updated and enabled.

Comment: Very weird! I am unable to recreate this. Could you attach a screenshot so I can see what you are experiencing?

Comment: We are looking into this.

Answer (score 1):

Generally this is solved cleaning your browsers' cookies. There is also an option for which cookies are stored from your IBM QuantumExperience account. Try modifying those, log out and log in again.